# Edge bundling for Cose-Bilkent in Cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm using the Cose-Bilkent layout to display a nested graph but it gets a bit messy when there are too many edges. To improve the graph in a visual way I was thinking about using some edge bundling for the graph. I've been doing some research and it seems I should be able to do this by setting things like control-point-step-size and/or control-point-weight but it is still not clear to me how to do that to be honest. My idea is to set that control point based on the position of some parent node. Below I attach a screenshot with a sketch of what I would like to get (sorry for the bad sketch). Could someone guide me a bit on how to get that parent control point and then set if for the edges? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/petQj.png) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have to add the control-point properties to your style :)
You can either use the [bezier edge-style](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/bezier-edges) or the [unbundled bezier edge-style](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/unbundled-bezier-edges)

```
var cy = cytoscape({

  container: yourContainer, // container to render in

  elements: yourElements,

  style: [ // the stylesheet for the graph
    {
      selector: 'node',
      style: {
        'background-color': yourColor,
        'label': yourLabel
      }
    },

    {
      selector: 'edge',
      style: {
        'width': 3,
        'line-color': '#ccc',
        'target-arrow-color': '#ccc',
        'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
        'curve-style': 'bezier',
        // 'curve-style': 'unbundled-bezier', // this is a manual bezier, maybe try out this one too
        'control-point-things': xyz
      }
    }
  ],

  layout: {
    name: yourLayout
  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks Stephan T. for your response. I've actually tried both `curve-style` types and the `unbundled bezier` one doesn't deal with self-loops (I get a lot of those in my data) so I'm going to probably stick with `bezier`. My main doubt is how to specify those `control-point-things` for compound nodes. Do I need to specify all parameters involved on control points such as `control-point-step-size`, `control-point-distance` and `control-point-weight`? It would help some simple example around how to specify those parameters...